# Mobile Service App Tablecontroller Post

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I can't seem to be able to post data using a TableController via postman.
I receive the following error:

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nPostPerson on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController\r\nSetDomainManager on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController\r\nSetContext on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController\r\nSetContext on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

Looks like the server can't find the route. However all other actions/verbs work just fine (Patch, delete, get).

IN postman this is the code:

```
POST /tables/person HTTP/1.1
```

Host: localhost:43689
ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 62bb9475-2b24-024a-b434-c9ddec0bcd9c

{
    "deleted": false,
    "id": "81FEF95A-2B61-4CE6-B9F7-FEBD572DADD1",
    "avatar": "",
    "notes": null,
    "lastName": "Trumpet",
    "middleName": "Ignacio",
    "firstName": "Donald",
    "userId": "81FEF95A-2B61-4CE6-B9F7-FEBD572DA876"
  }

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error message kind of gives it away.  Your code is problematic.  You need to post your code in order to gain assistance.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I managed to solve it before I got to post the code. The error was due to me adding the method DetDomainManager(DefaultMappedDomainManager<TData, TModel> domainManager) and that method for some reason got called twice, with the second time around having a null domainManager. 
I would like to take the time to thank you for the amazing work you and your team are doing on Azure and your guide on Mobile Apps. 
I noticed that there is no testing related chapters. I was going to add a few examples i come up with to test tablecontrollers against a mock database if you don't mind.

Comment: Chapter 8 is for testing... I'm *JUST* getting to that bit now!

Comment: Awesome! I look forward to learn how it should be properly done!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"**Multiple actions were found that match the request**: \r\n**PostPerson** on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController\r\n**SetDomainManager** on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController\r\n**SetContext** on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController\r\n**SetContext** on type CEVault.Backend.NetStandard.Controllers.Mobile.PersonController","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",

According to your error message, I assumed that there are some actions (`PostPerson`, `SetDomainManager`,`SetContext`) in your **PersonController.cs** which could both match your posted request.

Per my understanding, if you have some internal methods which are used to handle your business logic, you could mark them as protected or private instead of public. Or you could leverage `RouteAttribute` (e.g. `[Route("tables/TodoItem")]`) to mark your actions for attribute-based routing. When using `RouteAttribute`, you need to enable it by adding the following code in the `ConfigureMobileApp` method of your `Startup.MobileApp.cs`:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

For more details, you could follow Adrian Hall's [blog](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/).

Comment: Turns out i did put a SetDomainManager in my base tablecontroller class and it was getting called twice with a null domainmanager the second time around....